# Adverbs with suffix ‘-ly’ meaning ‘in a specific way’

Tags: adverbs

Can adverbs with suffix ‘-ly’ meaning ‘in a specific way’ be used only with an action word?

For example, doesn’t *I am **happily** ( in a happy way) in the bedroom* make sense because ‘am’ is not an action word?

Way: manner or method of doing or happening

I know it is true according to the dictionary, but I want to know about usage. People maybe use ‘way’ as if it means ‘manner or method of being something.’

Comment: _I am happily in the bedroom_ requires some other verb such as _sitting, waiting, resting_ - or whatever else you might be doing in your bedroom!

Comment: @KateBunting I have to disagree with that; we would not normally say "I am happily" by itself, but where there's a prepositional phrase like "in the bedroom", it's normal enough.  For example: ["Brandon - now comfortably and happily back home in the 1990s kitchen - says..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=BavvBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT181&dq=%22happily+back+home%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmqI7Xq-fvAhWyFVkFHfc2Dx0Q6AEwBnoECAMQAg)

Comment: @stangdon Yes, I did wonder about phrases involving _at/back home_, but couldn't think of a definite example.

Comment: No, you can use happily with am, because being in a location is a choice. I am happily at home; he is happily on the toilet; she is happily at Chicken Salad Chick.

Comment: Thank you guys :>